# Open different activity from list view in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a list view to display from data from firebase. From the [Listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGGcM.png), when the user clicks on "Test 1" it will open the "Cardio" type page for test 1. And if they click "Test 2" it opens an "Other" type page for test 2.

It does open the cardio and other pages but once the app is code. It doesn't open any of the pages. When you click on the items from the list view it doesn't do anything. And if I save a new workout, that one will work fine.

What do I need to add to make sure it opens the correct pages every time?

This is the code I'm using to open the pages.

```html
listViewWorkouts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
             WorkoutDB viewworkout = workoutList.get(i);

                if (viewworkout.getWorkoutCategory() == "Cardio"){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddCardioActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra(WORKOUT_ID, viewworkout.getWorkoutId());
                    intent.putExtra(WORKOUT_NAME, viewworkout.getWorkoutName());
                    intent.putExtra(WORKOUT_CATEGORY, viewworkout.getWorkoutCategory());
                    intent.putExtra(WORKOUT_DATE, viewworkout.getWorkoutDate());


                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (viewworkout.getWorkoutCategory() == "Other"){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddDetailActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra(WORKOUT_ID, viewworkout.getWorkoutId());
                    intent.putExtra(WORKOUT_NAME, viewworkout.getWorkoutName());
                    intent.putExtra(WORKOUT_CATEGORY, viewworkout.getWorkoutCategory());
                    intent.putExtra(WORKOUT_DATE, viewworkout.getWorkoutDate());


                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                
        });
```

Comment: use `.equals` instead of `==` while comparing `String` and most likely, you will be fine. Otherwise , debug and see what is going wrong. Is it not getting clicked ? is it not entering condition ? is it not opening the acitivity ? and provide details

Comment: if you need to launch 2 instances to open different activities  , why you just dont use buttons instead ? just 2 buttons with clickListeners will get you to each different class and send the Extras to that class, also im not understanding 100% your description of the problem.

Comment: try to use (ActivityName.this) instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: Thanks `.equals` works for me.

Comment: @MohanAdhikari Though my comment helped you , you should make a habit to accept one of the most relevant answers so that you get help next time quickly when you post question. Mark any one of the answers below that is more descriptive for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of  `viewworkout.getWorkoutCategory() == "Cardio"` use `viewworkout.equals("Cardio")`

The `==` operator tests whether two variables have the same references ( pointer to a memory address).

```
String foo = new String("abc");
String bar = new String("abc");

if(foo==bar)
// False (The objects are not the same)

bar = foo;

if(foo==bar)
// True (Now the objects are the same)
```

Whereas the `equals()` method tests whether two variables refer to objects that have the same state (values).

```
String foo = new String("abc");
String bar = new String("abc");

if(foo.equals(bar))
// True (The objects are identical but not same)
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> **equals()**

or **contain()** operation it recommended for string operations

> if (viewworkout.getWorkoutCategory().equals(Cardio){ }

also **==** used for int or somelse

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following method/(s) `.toLowerCase().equals("others")`